# Electron - How to pass JSON from main window to remote window?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, json, electron

I'm working with a total of 3 files.

`index.html`:

```
...
<a href="#" onclick="fetch(function(data) {console.log(data); subWindow(data)})">subWindow</a>
...
```

The `fetch()` function returns a `callback` in JSON format.

---

`subWindows.js`:

```
let micWindow

function subWindow(data) {
    micWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 1280,
        height: 800
    })

    console.log(data)

    micWindow.show()

    micWindow.loadFile('src/subWindow.html')
    micWindow.webContents.on('did-finish-load', function() {
        let javascript = `document.querySelector('body').innerHTML = '` + data + `'`
        micWindow.webContents.executeJavaScript(javascript)
    })
}
```

---

And finally `subWindow.html` which contains pure `html`. It also imports `subWindows.js`:

```
...
<!-- JS Imports -->
<script src="js/subWindows.js"></script>
...
```

---

**Firstly**, `index.html` console log prints JSON data for both `onclick` and `subWindow()` at `MIC.js?[sm]:10`. The `subWindow.html` shows `[object Object]` from `executeJavascript`, but the console is empty.

**Secondly**, doing the following doesn't work:

```
let javascript = `document.querySelector('body').innerHTML = '` + JSON.stringify(data) + `'`
```

or

```
 let javascript = 'console.log(' + data + ')'
```

Both throw an exception **`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`** in `subWindow.html`

JSON data isn't rendered by `subWindows.js` in `subWindow.html` but rather in `index.html`:

`index.html` imports `<script src="js/subWindows.js"></script>`

---

- **Why is it throwing an error?**
- **How to pass JSON data from main to remote window as function parameter?**

Preferably pass JSON to `executeJavascript` and inject it back into remote window's html.

Thanks for any feedback!

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure about the errors, but my solution is to put the data into the window by editing the HTML. Here is one way to do this:

```
// win is the window you are passing info to
var data = win.document.createElement('span');
data.innerHTML = json;
win.document.body.appendChild(data);
```

The program in the window would wait for the element to appear, and then use the value for the function.

Note:
I just noticed that your JavaScript doesn't have any semicolons at the end of the lines. You need to have one after every statement. :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer @mega12345mega and just to clarify I didn't downvote your post. This isn't a valid solution as `let javascript = "document.querySelector('body').innerHTML = 'TEST'"` does work in this scenario regardless of semicolon. JSON data somehow remains in `index.html` at execution, explaining why `console.log(data)` (including `function subWindow(data){console.log(data)}`) prints twice while `subWindow.html`'s console is empty. The remote window appears to read `[object Object]` but printing that into the console results in the error; no need to wait for elements to appear first.

Comment: @user13581602 I just looked it up, and apparently semicolons aren't required if there is a line break, but it is good practice to do so. I was always taught differently! Anyways, if [object Object] is appearing, the JSON data must be converting to a string without the use of JSON.stringify(object). Try using it without the qoutes outside of it - it looks like in the question you tested ```let javascript = `document.querySelector('body').innerHTML = '` + JSON.stringify(data) + `'```. Try just ```let javascript = document.querySelector('body').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data)```